# VBA compare string ( check if string one contains string 2)

Tags: string, excel, vba, compare, string-comparison

I am having a problem with comparing two strings. The method does not seem to work somehow. I have tried the following to functions:

1. Method:

   ```
   If StrComp(logic_string, RSTA_ISIN_clean) Then
       rng.Offset(0, 16) = "OK(ISIN in RSTA)"
       rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 5296274
   Else
       rng.Offset(0, 16) = "NG(ISIN not RSTA or check RSTA)"
       rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 255
   End If
   ```
2. Method:

   ```
    If InStr(1, RSTA_ISIN_clean, logic_string, vbTextCompare) Then
        rng.Offset(0, 16) = "OK(ISIN in RSTA)"
        rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 5296274
    Else
        rng.Offset(0, 16) = "NG(ISIN not RSTA or check RSTA)"
        rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 255
    End If
   ```

in logic_string I have the value "FR0012915700" and in RSTA_ISIN i have the value = " Old ISIN: FR0012915700"

All I am trying to do is to check if  RSTA_ISIN  is in logic_string and if so i want to write OK in cell. (trying to get a contains method here)

It can be that something is wrong with logic_string as it sometimes gives me spaces -> so logic_string looks like this in debug mode "   FR0004052561" -> I tried to trim the spaces with Trim but that doesn't work either.

I have also tried the InStr function but that doesn't work either

Can someone assist please

This is what I get in debug mode:

[image]

Comment: When trying the code on my system I am getting a match with the function and the TRIM also looks to be working. Can you advise how the values of RSTA_ISIN_clean and logic_String are set?

Comment: Code is working fine for me too

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I want to check whether RSTA_ISIN is in logic_string or in other words whether logic_string contains RSTA_ISIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your variable. "RSTA_ISIN_clean" or "RSTA_ISIN" as variable

```
Sub test1()

Dim RSTA_ISIN_clean As String
Dim logic_string As String
Dim Rng As Range


Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 30)

logic_string = "FR0012915700"

RSTA_ISIN_clean = "Old ISIN: FR0012915700"

logic_string = Trim(logic_string)
RSTA_ISIN_clean = Trim(RSTA_ISIN_clean)


If StrComp(logic_string, RSTA_ISIN_clean) Then
    Rng.Offset(0, 16) = "OK(ISIN in RSTA)"
    Rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 5296274
Else
    Rng.Offset(0, 16) = "NG(ISIN not RSTA or check RSTA)"
    Rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 255
End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound to me that you actually want to use the [StrCmp function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s233cfc(v=vs.90).aspx) at all; it sounds as if your *find-string-within-another-string* should be handled by the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Please click those links and read the MSDN documentation to make a decision.

```
Dim logic_string as String, RSTA_ISIN_clean as String

logic_string = "FR0012915700"
RSTA_ISIN_clean = " Old ISIN: FR0012915700"

If CBool(InStr(1, RSTA_ISIN_clean, logic_string, vbTextCompare)) Then
    rng.Offset(0, 16) = "OK(ISIN in RSTA)"
    rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 5296274
Else
    rng.Offset(0, 16) = "NG(ISIN not RSTA or check RSTA)"
    rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 255
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Like Operator:

```
Dim logic_string As String, RSTA_ISIN_clean As String

  logic_string = " FR0012915700"
  RSTA_ISIN_clean = " Old ISIN: FR0012915700"


 If RSTA_ISIN_clean Like "*" & Trim(logic_string) & "*" Then
    Rng.Offset(0, 16) = "OK(ISIN in RSTA)"
    Rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 5296274
 Else
    Rng.Offset(0, 16) = "NG(ISIN not RSTA or check RSTA)"
    Rng.Offset(0, 16).Interior.Color = 255
 End If`
```